# Python strange NameError for def

Tags: python, nameerror

My code isnt too long so here is the whole program, when i run it it says

> NameError: name 'xmlp' is not defined for line 88

It seems too simple, whats happening here ?
It worked just before i took extract and copied it and renamed it to `xmlp`, i then made a new button to execute it but then it broke, why does it say its not defined when it very clearly is ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

interface = tk.Tk()
interface.geometry("900x500")
interface.title("Text display")

T = tk.Text(interface, height=20, width=150)
T.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=3)

def openfile(): # open your file and load it into the text widget

    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(filename)
    file = open(filename)
    global txt
    txt = file.read()

    T.delete('1.0', END)
    T.insert(tk.END, txt)

    return txt

def extract(): # take the opened file and write it to a text file
    open('somefile.txt', 'w').close()

    root = ET.fromstring(txt)

    str_params = root.findall('.//parameter/[parameterid="str"]')
    for param in str_params:
        if param.find('./name').text == 'Text':
            print(format(param.find('./value').text))
            with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                the_file.write(format(param.find('./value').text))
                the_file.write("\n")

    exportFileDir = open('somefile.txt',)

    txtExport = exportFileDir.read()

    T.delete('1.0', END)
    T.insert(tk.END,txtExport)

    def xmlp():  # take the opened file and write it to a text file
        open('somefile.txt', 'w').close()

        root = ET.fromstring(txt)

        str_params = root.findall('.//parameter/[parameterid="str"]')
        for param in str_params:
            if param.find('./name').text == 'Text2':
                print(format(param.find('./value').text))
                with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                    the_file.write(format(param.find('./value').text))
                    the_file.write("\n")

        exportFileDir = open('somefile.txt', )

        txtExport = exportFileDir.read()

        T.delete('1.0', END)
        T.insert(tk.END, txtExport)



def file_save():
    f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if f is None: # asksaveasfile return `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
        return
    exportFileDir = open('somefile.txt')

    txtExport = exportFileDir.read()

    f.write(txtExport)
    f.close() # `()` was missing.

button = ttk.Button(interface, text="Open text File", command=openfile)  # <------
button.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky = W)

buttonex = ttk.Button(interface, text="Extract subtitles", command=extract)  # <------
buttonex.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky = W)

buttonexp = ttk.Button(interface, text="X XML P", command=xmlp)  # <------
buttonexp.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky = W)

buttonsv = ttk.Button(interface, text="Save as", command=file_save)  # <------
buttonsv.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky = W)

interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `xmlp` function is inside another function so it is defined only on the scope of that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **indentation (spacing and tabs)** problem here.
Let's say you copied a function 'function2'. What you did is:

```
def function1():
    print('hello 1')

    def function2():
        print('hello 2')

def function3():
    print('hello 3')
```

But the correct way is:

```
def function1():
    print('hello 1')

def function2():
    print('hello 2')

def function3():
    print('hello 3')
```

Comment: I see thank you so much, ive been stuck in java for a few months and completely forgot about this

Comment: Also, while copying from somewhere, keep in mind that sometimes instead of tabs ('\t'), spaces are copied and you might get "indentation error". So you will have to erase the spaces and put tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a function within a function:

```
def hi():
    def hello():
        print("Hello")
    hello()
    print("Hi")
hello()  # <- Error
```

which will exist only in the function's local scope.

Move the function outside of the function or (in case you really really want to use such solution) use `global` to define it in the global namespace:

```
def hi():
    global hello
    def hello():
        print("Hello")
    hello()
    print("Hi")
hello()  # <- No error, after hi()
```

Note that the function (`hi()`) that **defines** the inner function (`hello()`) needs to be called first in this case to execute `global <name>` so the function is stored into the `global` namespace instead of the `local` one.